# How many Titantite Slabs are in Dark Souls 3?

Tags: dark-souls-3

The DS3 Wiki states there are 15 total slabs possible.

On my new-game character I have 5 fully upgraded weapons and 10 slabs, but I haven't defeated Midir, so Shira couldn't have given her slab to me yet.

My fully upgraded weapons are

- The Rotten Ghru Dagger
- The Lothric Sword
- The Hollowslayer Greatsword
- The Exile Greatsword
- And the Four-Pronged Plow

If I kill Midir I could have 16 fully upgraded weapons on this play through. How is that possible?

Comment: Quick clarification, none of the assists that came to your world dropped a slab for you? That's an easy way to boost the total number of slabs in your game.

Comment: @GGMG You cannot transfer upgrade materials

Comment: @Ben Hm... apparently, guess the guy who dropped mine was a hacker, wouldn't be the weirdest thing I've seen happen. Beg pardon, looks like dropping slabs isn't the answer. Although you can apparently trade upgraded gear if you've got another piece of gear of an equal or higher value, [roughly speaking](https://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Player+Trade). Don't suppose you remember trading any of that gear?

Comment: I promise that I haven't taken any candy from strangers. I also promise my save is not a hacked one. I'll post screenshots when I'm home from work.

Comment: Would it be disallowed to post a link to a download of my save? Is that a bannable offense on this community?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Shira drops it if you kill her in the ruins at the end of the world but your character hasn't yet defeated Midir.

[This wiki page](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Shira,_Knight_of_Filianore) states that she has a guaranteed drop rate of the slab if she hasn't yet awarded it to you.

I'm guessing that Midir's defeat will not yield a Titantite Slab from Shira.

**Update**

That is exactly what happened.

Answer (score 2):

The only way this might have happened is if another player dropped a +10 weapon for you. You can only transfer those if you already have a fully upgraded weapon (+10 with regular Titanite, or +5 with Titanite Scale).

So for example, if you already had the +5 Hollowslayer Greatsword, someone would be capable of dropping another +10 weapon.